# How to use and define CRUD?

Tags: crud, use-case

I want to use more than one CRUD in the same Use Case diagram. Can I define a name for each CRUD? How can I distinguish them?
Otherwise both would be named CRUD.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Use Case Diagram Level of Description that is in use in your model. For example, a simple high level (say 1) CRUD case use name for some entity, could be "entity management" (by example "User management").

I recommend the usage (in the high level) of words like "administration" or "management" instead CRUD.

CRUD is too technical and the use case diagrams and descriptions are artifacts to improve the communication between stakeholders.